# Paste option in XPM 2013

Tags: experience-manager

I am trying to copy and paste some text in RTF using XPM and on IE 11 but the text is not getting appearing on the page. Tried using "Paste" as well "Special paste" but nothing works.
Plz help

Comment: Is your Browser [configured for XPM per the documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-27B41DA9-CAC6-4311-B824-192E15DA56EB)?  Double check to see if you have `Allow Programmatic clipboard access` set. Do you see the same behavior in the Component form view for Rich Text Format areas? Otherwise report your specific versions for XPM and IE along with any browser console errors to Support.

Answer (score 1):

Please note as per the XPM User Manual, this is a known issue as you may sometime in some browser can not copy (and paste) if you are using the mouse. Following two options I could suggest:

- Instead of using mouse to choose Copy/Paste, use short cut for Copy (ctrl+c) and Paste (ctrl+v)
- Use some other browser

You may refer to the XPM User Manual [HERE](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/images/SDL%20Tridion%202013%20Experience%20Manager%20Basic%20User%20Manual_tcm89-20974.pdf)

I hope it helps.